# R.java not generating with spring and Maven

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, r.java-file

I was making an android project , with `spring and maven` and when there is a target folder where `R.java` is present 
But when do Maven Install it gives error that R.java not there..
I have tried all other posts , nothing is helping ,

R.java is not generating even after clean.

Answer (score 1):

Are you developing your Android project inside Eclipse? In which case some work is needed to get the ADT to play nice with Maven/M2Eclipse. Please see my project:

https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/m2eclipse-android-integration/

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your generated R class isn't generated, it indicates that there's a problem with generating it due to some parsing issue from the XML resources. Check the error console in your IDE to figure out what's specifically wrong.

Common problems are:

- An unescaped character in your `strings.xml`, for instance `you're` instead of `you\'re`
- Missing `layout_width` or `layout_height` tags in layout resources
- Missing namespace declarations
- Variable names that aren't supported by Java, for instance due to capitalization or use of spaces, hyphens or other unsupported characters
- Any other kind of syntax error in XML
- Check **Console** and **Probelm** Tab for the Issues